# positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, economics

For general linear model : y=XB+u , u~N(0,(ssq)I) , u are i.i.d

Let b* be the OLS estimator of B ,ie. b*=inv(X'X)X'y .

Let b be any linear unbiased estimator of B having the form : b=Hy where H doesn't depend on y .

We want to see which one is more effective , b or b* :

By unbiasedness , E[b]=E[HXB+Hu]=HXB=B , which implies HX=I

Define C by H=inv(X'X)X'+C , then HX=I implies CX=0 .
Thus b=Hy=[inv(X'X)X'+C]y=b*+Cy=b*+Cu (it can be shown that Cy=Cu)

To see which one is more effective , Cov(b)=Cov(b*)+ ssqCC' which gives Cov(b)-Cov(b*)=ssqCC' . The difference being p.s.d (thus b* is more effective estimator).

My question is that how can CC' be p.s.d ? I tried to use CX=0 but it looks very tricky becuause neither C nor X has to be 0 , could someone help ?

Comment: It would be much better to typeset your math symbols and equations to improve legibility (e.g. see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

For a real symmetric matrix $A$, the definition of $A$ being positive semidefinite is that $x^T A x \geq 0$ for all $x$. Can this be applied here?

Comment: ok I'll learn to type math symbol , and below answer showed that x'Ax>=0 can be applied here by writing x'CC'x as a dot product which must be non negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$CC'$ is positive semidefinite because we can write

$$x'CC'x=\|C'x\|^2 \ge 0$$

We do not require $CX=0$.

Comment: I do know the definition of p.s.d matrices , but I cannot show CC' is p.s.d from information given above : 1. CX=0 2.Cy=Cu 3. C=H-inv(X'X)X'

Comment: It holds true for any matrix $C$. no further property required. Or perhaps we have misunderstood your question, can you elaborate?

Comment: I think my question is : could you show CC' (defined as above) is p.s.d. , e.g. why you can write x'CC'x

Comment: $A$ is positive semidefinite  means $x'Ax \ge 0$ for all $x$. hence we want to examine the quantity $x'Ax$. Here $A=CC'$. now we can group $x'CC'x=(x'C)(C'x) = \|C'x\|^2$.

Comment: but CC' is not given to be p.s.d , I need to show it to be p.s.d in order to reach conclusion

Comment: e.g. I've learned a few ways to show a matrix is p.s.d. 1. all eigenvalue >= 0 2.your method 3.all leading determinants >=0 4. all pivots in elimination >=0

Comment: e.g to show CC' is p.s.d , you can write out its eigenvalues and show those eigenvalues are >=0 (although it doesn't seem to be possible in this question)

Comment: I have proven that $CC'$ is postiive definie, since I show that $x'CC'x$ can be written as a square of a real number.

Comment: I see , very sorry I overlooked that , thanks a lot !